# Probabilities using a deck of cards

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, conditional-probability

So I have a deck with $36$ cards containing $4$ aces. After extracting $3$ random cards:

1. What is the probability of being EXACTLY $1$ ace in those $3$ cards?
2. What is the probability of being AT LEAST an ace in those $3$ cards?

I have trouble differentiating the $2$ problems. So for the first problem, the first card drawn has a chance of $\frac{32}{36}$. Assuming it wasn't an ace the second one is $\frac{31}{35}$, and the third one $\frac{30}{34}$. The probability is $P = 1 -  \frac{32}{36} * \frac{31}{35} * \frac{30}{34}$. Am I approaching this correctly? And as far as the second one goes, I have no idea. What is the correct approach for this type of problem?

Comment: Hint: (a) What is the probability of picking 2 cards out of 35 (excluding one of the aces) and how many different ways you can leave an ace out? These two together should get you to the answer

(b) Use counting. Look at the first card being an ace and don't put any restrictions on the others, that way, you are allowing at least 1 ace instead of exactly 1. Then, look at permutations.

Comment: The solution you present is correct for the second part (at least one ace)

Comment: My solution was for the first problem, the one with exactly one ace. :)

Comment: I know you intended it for the first, that's why I pointed out that it actually applies to the second. Also, use @username so that the user will receive notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question asks you to find the probability that there is exactly one ace, no more, no less. Your sample space consists of one out of four aces and two non aces in this case.
The second part asks you to find the probability that there is at least one ace. In this case, your sample space can contain

1. One out of four aces, and two non aces.
2. Two out of four aces, and one non ace.
3. Three out of four aces.

Easier way to approach the second problem would be to consider the complement of the sample space, i.e., no card is an ace. Can you take it further?

As for your solution, you counted the probability for first three cards being a non ace and subtracted from $1$. That means you are counting the probability of complement of an event $E$ where $E$ is no card is an ace. Hence $E^C$ means at least one card is an ace. So indirectly, you solved the second problem.

Hint: For the first part, pick any one ace in $4\choose 1$ ways and select remaining $2$ cards out of $32$ in $32 \choose 2$ ways.

Comment: So the probability for the first part would be 32/36 * 31/35 * 4/34 right? Since the first 2 would be the 2 non-ace cards and the last one would be the ace.

Comment: @Oscar Not quite, you need to multiply the result by $3$ to account for the ace being in any position.

Comment: @OscarTheMighty I would suggest find instances of sample space and find instances of all possibilities separately in such problems. For part I, possible ways to draw EXACTLY one ace means we have to select one ace out of four [in $4\choose 1$ ways] and select $2$ cards out of $32$ non aces [in $32 \choose 2$ ways]. Hence, our sample space consists of ${32\choose 2} \cdot {4\choose 1}$ discrete events. 

On other hand, we have total number of possibilities equal to $36\choose 3$, i.e., we can choose any three cards out of 36. Hence probability is $\frac{4\times {32\choose 2}}{36\choose 3}$

Comment: @OscarTheMighty Yes. Look at Daniel Mathias' comment. I have also added a more detailed explanation to make it clearer. Sorry I did not notice the lack of $3$. My bad

Comment: @PythonSage Thanks for the detailed explanations, I finally understand these things better. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe for part b) you need to consider all the cases where you have at least 2 aces. You could get all 3 aces, what's the probability of that? You could get one Ace, what's the probability of that? You want to know what the probability of ANY of the success cases occurring is. Part a) seems like a part of b). I think you might find this website helpful: [Random Services](https://www.randomservices.org/random/apps/BallUrnExperiment.html)

Answer (score 1):

For $i=1,2,3$ let $A_i$ denote the event that the $i$-th draw results in an ace.

In 1) you are asked to find: $$P(A_1\cap A_2^{\complement}\cap A_3^{\complement})+P(A_1^{\complement}\cap A_2\cap A_3^{\complement})+P(A_1^{\complement}\cap A_2^{\complement}\cap A_3)$$

The first term can be calculated as:$$P(A_1\cap A_2^{\complement}\cap A_3^{\complement})=P(A_1)P(A_2^{\complement}\mid A_1)P(A_3^{\complement}\mid A_1\cap A_2^{\complement})=\frac4{36}\frac{32}{35}\frac{31}{34}$$

Symmetry tells us that for the other terms we get the same outcome so the final answer is: $$3\times\frac4{36}\frac{32}{35}\frac{31}{34}$$

(Also you can go for finding every term separately in order to convince yourself that symmetry works here)

In 2) you are asked to find:$$P(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)$$

In cases like this (characterized by "at least" or "at most") very often it is handsome to for the complement:$$P(A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3)=1-P(A_1^{\complement}\cap A_2^{\complement}\cap A_3^{\complement})=1-P(A_1^{\complement})P(A_2^{\complement}\mid A_1^{\complement})P(A_3^{\complement}\mid A_1^{\complement}\cap A_2^{\complement})=$$$$1-\frac{32}{36}\frac{31}{35}\frac{30}{34}$$